# getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in java swing

Tags: java, exception, hashset, concurrentmodification

getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` when the following code get executed several times on clicking the button

```
for(Iterator <PrintWriter> it=TABhs.iterator();it.hasNext();)
                    { 
                        PrintWriter ot=it.next();
                        ot.println("tableupdate#"+tables+"#"+kotno+"#processing");
                        ot.flush();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "<html><body>Table Kot Status Changed to <b>Processing</b></body></html>");
                    }
```

can anyone tell me some solutions for this

here TABhs is HashSet with PrintWriter generics

```
HashSet <PrintWriter> TABhs=new HashSet<PrintWriter>();
```

button click action is shown below

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      String stat=status_combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
      String tables=tableno_combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
      String kotno=kotno_combo.getSelectedItem().toString();

      if(stat.equals("Processing"))
      {
            try {
                String quer="UPDATE table_orders SET status='"+stat.toLowerCase()+"' WHERE tableno='"+tables+"' AND kotno='"+kotno+"'";  
                int restatus=dbGetDet.insertDetails(quer);
                if(restatus>0){
                filtercomboBox();
                fillTable();
                for(Iterator <PrintWriter> it=TABhs.iterator();it.hasNext();)
                { 
                    PrintWriter ot=it.next();
                    ot.println("tableupdate#"+tables+"#"+kotno+"#processing");
                    ot.flush();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "<html><body>Table Kot Status Changed to <b>Processing</b></body></html>");
                }



                    System.out.println("TABhs--------------------->"+TABhs.size());
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MYClientclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other threads modifying the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    TABhs = new CopyOnWriteArraySet(TABhs);
    for(Iterator <PrintWriter> it=TABhs.iterator();it.hasNext();)
    { 
          PrintWriter ot=it.next();
          ot.println("tableupdate#"+tables+"#"+kotno+"#processing");
          ot.flush();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "<html><body>Table Kot Status Changed to <b>Processing</b></body></html>");
    }
```

Comment: sir what's this CopyOnWriteArraySet()

Comment: It is thread-safe Set implementation.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html

Comment: getting exception like------------ cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method CopyOnWriteArraySet()
  location: class kotouch.MYClientclass

Comment: updated in answer. forgot to add new. and import  this import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet;

Comment: now i'm getting----------incompatible types
  required: java.util.HashSet<java.io.PrintWriter>
  found:    java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet

Comment: Change HashSet <PrintWriter> TABhs=new HashSet<PrintWriter>(); to  Set <PrintWriter> TABhs=new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

Comment: sir it working now.......but one problem.........my application runs a socket server program as a thread for accepting new clients......when a client joins ......it adds its PrintWriter object to TABhs ......... so that the server has all clients obejcts.....in case for sending some messages to all clients i do the above iteration.....but the problem is that when sever sends message the size of TABhs increased everytime...........